# How to quickly test new Boost versions and libraries?

Tags: c++, boost

As many C++ programmers, I really appreciate the Boost libraries, and use them in many projects. Consequently, I like to keep myself up-to-date with the new libraries that get added regularly.

However, I often find myself wanting to try some new features without installing again another version on my computer. Basically, I would like to be able to try out some code snippets rapidly, without going through the burden of downloading the sources and compiling them.

I tried to do so on online compilers such as [ideone](http://www.ideone.com) or [codepad](http://codepad.org), but the versions of Boost they provide are not quite up-to-date ([1.39 for ideone](http://www.ideone.com/Vuueb) and [1.34 for codepad](http://codepad.org/gRLx6S1S)).

Do you know any online compiler that will let me test the latest versions of Boost? If not, how do you proceed to test only some library? If I do a partial checkout of the svn repository, how can I be sure that I fetched all dependencies?

Comment: gentoo linux could have multiple boost versions installed in parallel and you could choose which one should be active. I think the binary version `sabayon` also has this features. Maybe you should have a look at that

Answer (score 3):

Just make a virtual machine (VirtualBox is good and free), install the OS on it, make a "snapshot" of the VM, then install your dev packages like the latest Boost.  If it isn't what you want, roll back to the snapshot and install other things.  Once you have a configuration you like, clone that VM and keep trying new ones on one of the clones.

Comment: The major issue I have is not having several versions of Boost at the same time on my machine, it is that I don't want to waste hard-drive space by installing hundreds of MB of libraries just to test one little feature. I would also appreciate not having to spend too much time downloading/compiling all the libraries, and just focus on the ones I am interested in. In this regard, a VM would not really help me.

Comment: A 1 TB disk now costs $45.  It is literally not worth our time discussing saving "hundreds of MB" of disk space on a single desktop.  As far as not spending as much time downloading and compiling, how about using the pre-packaged Boost versions?  For example on Fedora or Red Hat or Ubuntu you can easily install a "current stable" version for each distribution release, and often one or two other versions as well (e.g. using rpmfusion or EPEL if you're on a Fedora/Red Hat system).

Comment: @John there are more subtle issues involved.  Let's say you are testing a low latency system that is specifically run on bare metal (not via a vm).  In this case, the VM gives you no information about resultant performance

Comment: @Foo Bah: are you making up new requirements for the OP?  He said "I would like to be able to try out some code snippets rapidly."  Doesn't sound like some kind of super-optimized system for which running in a VM will ruin his results.

Answer (score 0):

There's a real difficulty with using multiple versions of boost.  I made a request a long time ago to add relevant environment variables or macros to be able to support multiple versions of boost.

I do two things:

1) Parallel dev server, which I use for testing the newest version of libraries (not just boost).

2) virtual machines for quick compilation.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is checkout a local copy of latest boost library from svn and install the library to a local directory(change the install prefix).

Also following options in the `bootstrap.sh` file would help you build/install only the library component(s) you are interested in

```
148   --show-libraries          show the set of libraries that require build
149                             and installation steps (i.e., those libraries
150                             that can be used with --with-libraries or
151                             --without-libraries), then exit
152   --with-libraries=list     build only a particular set of libraries,
153                             describing using either a comma-separated list of
154                             library names or "all"
155                             [all]
156   --without-libraries=list  build all libraries except the ones listed []
```

Experimenting this with a checked out copy from svn helps as you can always update what you have downloaded with the latest(desired) version and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try online compiler on this page: http://apolukhin.github.io/Boost-Cookbook-4880OS . Most recent boost version at the moment. And you can fork this site and maintain it by your own (in case of the owner abandon it)